# Better, cleaner way to write this jQuery code

Tags: jquery, optimization, click, jquery-animate

I currently have this written but the title says is there a better way to write/optimize  this code?

```
var p = $('#pstrip');

$('a.Btn1').click(function() {
    p.animate({left: '0px'});
});
$('a.Btn2').click(function() {
    p.animate({left: '-730px'});
});
$('a.Btn3').click(function() {
    p.animate({left: '-1460px'});
});
$('a.Btn4').click(function() {
    p.animate({left: '-2190px'});
});
$('a.Btn5').click(function() {
    p.animate({left: '-2920px'});
});
```

Comment: For questions on optimizing working code, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In this and also the suggested answers, you might want to preventDefault() on the <a> elements as well. If they have values, the clicks will try to load those (either page anchors or links).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is shorten it, something like this could work.

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5], function(idx, el) {
    var ix = idx;
    $('a.Btn' + el).click(function() {
        p.animate({left: (-730*ix) + 'px'});
    });
})
```

**EDIT**: Oops, the parameters were backwards.
**EDIT 2**: As Imp noted below we need to make sure it calls correctly - I just did a different way

Comment: This is not a "better" or "cleaner" way. In fact, this is worse than the original code: http://jsperf.com/five-buttons/2

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I'm not arguing that there are better ways, but I would argue that to someone who is wondering about changing a relatively simple piece of code as this, your method is less readable and perhaps therefore less useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
var p = $('#pstrip');
var coords = [0, -730, -1460, -2190, -2920];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    $('a.Btn' + (i + 1)).click((function(index) {
        return function() {
            p.animate({left: coords[index]});
        }
    })(i));
```

I put the coordinates into array and cycled through the `a.Btn` elements, so that (i+1)-th element is associated with the i-th coordinate. The function that is to be bound to the `click` event is not specified directly, but instead returned by an immediately invoked function expression. The reason is that if I just plainly wrote

```
.click(function() { p.animate({left: coords[i]}); })
```

then all callback functions would refer to the same `i` in closure, which would have value `5` at the time.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more efficient on load, as it only makes one call to `.click()`:

```
$("#button_container a").click(function() {
    $("#pstrip").animate({left: ($(this).attr("class").match(/Btn([0-9]+)/)[1] * -730) + "px"});
});
```

This has the added benefit of being able to add more buttons without having to modify the javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This starts out by selecting all anchors who have a class that begins with `Btn`. It then binds to all of them an anonymous function that determines the number of pixels `#pstrip` will be shifted.

```
$("a[class^=Btn]").on("click", function(){
  var n = -730 * ( this.className.match(/\d+/) - 1 );
  $("#pstrip").animate({ left: n + 'px' });
});
```

This will work with any number of anchors.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ovibun/5/edit
Performance: http://jsperf.com/five-buttons/3

[image]